# opencv set camera resolution windows vrs linux

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

Questions that are variations of this occur, but not this error situation.

This codeworks on Linux, it Fails on windows10 OpenCV 3.4.2, 64bit -Python 3.6 - installed via "pip3 install opencv-python"

It fails on Windows with the error message below.

If I remove the 'cv2.set()' for the horz and virt size it works, without problem but the resolution is not what I want

My goal is to change from the default image size to the LARGER size.

```
v=3.4.2
Camera H=480, W=640
Camera H=480, W=640
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072875855
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072875855
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072875855
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
```

This is the Python code

```
import cv2
print("v=%s" % cv2.__version__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.)
h = cap.get( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )
w = cap.get( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
print("Camera H=%d, W=%d" % (h,w) )
# If I remove these two lines it works but is stuck at 640x480
cap.set( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 10000 )
cap.set( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 10000 )
h = cap.get( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )
w = cap.get( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
print("Camera H=%d, W=%d" % (h,w) )

while(True):
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to work around this by switching to the DSHOW backend API:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Comment: Thanks - that is the solution - to be clear, the cv2.CAP_DSHOW is an add value. If you want to open camera 1, you do this: (cv2.CAP_DSHOW+1)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to brianpeiris for the solution, I'm just documenting it here in a more formal way

The cv2.CAP_DSHOW is a flag passed as part of the open call, there are many others you can pass, and this CAP_DSHOW is Microsoft specific.

```
import cv2

camera_number = 0

c = cv2.VideoCapture( camera_number + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
# this picks the LARGEST image possible
c.set( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 10000 )
c.set( cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 10000 )

while True:
    a,f = c.read()
    if not a:
         continue
    cv2.imshow( "it-works", f )
    k=cv2.waitKey(10)
    # press q to quit.
    if k == ord('q'):
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to select the source index, the answer in [this comment](http://answers.opencv.org/question/197480/change-camera-size-fails-on-windows-works-on-linux/?answer=198085#post-id-198085) works pretty well.

```
videoSourceIndex = 1
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW + videoSourceIndex)
```